# How to change Time/Timezone on Google Chrome from Develop

Tags: google-chrome, time, timezone, developer-tools

I am trying to understand how to change my time and/or timezone manually by using inspect. Could someone give me an explanation on how to do it, and the meaning of 'Timezone override is already in effect'?

Much appreciated!
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sspsr.png)